# Issue with docker swarm and named volumes

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-swarm, bitcoin, docker-volume

I'm having some issues using named volumes in one of my docker stacks.

Basically I'm running a bitcoin node developed by bcoin. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the containers running the nodes to write and read the blockchain data from a Digital Ocean volume attached to one of my droplets (VMs). I'm guessing I'm having some issues because I normally use volumes one way only, having stuff in my host machine being present in my containers.

This DO volume is present in the directory `/mnt/blockchain-data` in my manager node (or droplet).

So here's my docker-stack.yml file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  bcoin:
    image: hollarves/bcoin-mueve
    ports:
      #-- Mainnet
      # - "8333:8333"
      # - "8332:8332" # RPC/HTTP
      # - "8334:8334" # Wallet
      #-- Testnet
      - "18333:18333"
      - "18332:18332" # RPC/HTTP
      - "18334:18334"
    networks:
      - bitcoin-private-net
    volumes:
      - blockchain:/data
      - ${PWD}/bitcoin/secrets/bcoin.conf:/data/bcoin.conf
      - ${PWD}/bitcoin/secrets/wallet.conf:/data/wallet.conf
    environment:
      BCOIN_CONFIG: /data/bcoin.conf
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.docker.network=bitcoin-net"
        - "traefik.bcoin.frontend.rule=Host:bcoin.xxxx.com"
        - "traefik.bcoin.backend=bcoin"
        - "traefik.bcoin.port=18332"
        - "traefik.bcoin.frontend.entryPoints=http"
        - "traefik.bcoin-wallet.frontend.rule=Host:bcoin-wallet.xxxx.com"
        - "traefik.bcoin-wallet.backend=bcoin-wallet"
        - "traefik.bcoin-wallet.port=18334"
        - "traefik.bcoin-wallet.frontend.entryPoints=http"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

volumes:
  blockchain:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: bind
      device: :/mnt/blockchain-data

networks:
  bitcoin-private-net:
    external: true
```

So basically I want whatever is in the `/data` directory of my containers to be synced with whatever it is in my `/mnt/blockchain-data` in my host machine. If the container writes some new blocks they should be copied to the `/mnt/blockchain-data` dir, and if a new bitcoin node is replicated, it should already have it's data directory synced with the files in my host machine.

The main idea is to avoid redownloading the blockchain whenever a node is destroyed and recreated for whatever reason. As well as being able to replicate as many nodes I want without having to download the blockchain for each one of them.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly the error docker returns? Or it does not return, and the folder is not sync?

Comment: Yeah, no errors and no logs whatsoever. The service simply refuses to starts staying at 0/1 replicas all the time.

Comment: I tried docker service logs and docker container logs and nothing.

Comment: Then, do `docker service ps <service> --no-trunc` to see what was the exit error (if logs show nothing)

Comment: That was it, I realized thanks to this command that the DO volume had a different name that what I entered when creating it, changing a `-` to `_`. Pretty simple stuff but very frustrating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve your goal, especially in a swarm environnement.
At first, let's say that docker does not sync volumes among swarm, unless you use a suited driver.
Thus, you'll have to use drivers or other solutions, according to whether you need r/w or only read!

Here are a few ideas (not all solutions!) :

- You may mount share drive among the machines hosting your nodes, by exemple [NFS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04). Ensure they are mounted on the same path on all hosts. Then, just bind mound the path to you container /data. Though, this is not the easiest way. But if you need R/W options, this is a suited solution. However, note that this solution can be seen as introducing a [SPOOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure), which is not that great in production environnement.
- you may use named volume as well, but in a distributed environment, you will have to use a volume driver to be able to sync them. Docker doc has [a few exemples](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#share-data-among-machines). You have a list of volume plugings [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#volume-plugins). According to which one you choose, you may eliminate the SPOOF problem.
- Eventually, if you don't need r/w possibilities, swarm mode allow you to use [secrets](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets)/[configs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#configs). Especially, [secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) are obviously suited to such sensitive data as yours.

Hope this helps!